# how to use setState in SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter

I want to add more filter on search result by adding a form with some radio buttons and other widgets. The doc states that `Radio` does not keep state and should call parent's `setState` `onChange` method to rebuild widget. The form will be displayed after calling `showModalBottomSheet`. 
Looking at `search.dart` looks like setState is called internally only on query changed

**what i did** 
assuming there was no such method, `setState`, I redisplay dialogue, call `Navigation.pop(context)` followed by `showModalBottomSheet`. The radio buttons can now update the value onChanged but the transition to redislay the dialogue looks ugly (sliding animation every time the value changes).

Is it possible to use setState in searchDelegate and how?

Comment: I wraped ListView inside Scaffold with FAB on buildResults. on FAB clicked i `showModalBottomSheet` with Radio buttons in it. the problem was, I could not immediately see changes in selected radio button. Thanks

Comment: I was looking for setState in searchDelegate, just realized that it has nothing to do with it. Just wrap my dialogue with StatefulBuilder then im good, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to use is `StatefulBuilder`, returned by `showModalBottomSheet`'s builder.

`StatefulBuilder` provides `setState` method to rebuild its own subtree.

e.g.

```dart
int selected;

showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (_) =>
  StatefulBuilder(builder: (modalContext, modalSetState) =>
    Column(children: <Widget>[

      Text("Select radio button"),
      RadioListTile(
        value: 1,
        groupValue: selected,
        onChanged: (val) => modalSetState(() => selected = val),
        title: Text("One")
      ),
      RadioListTile(
        value: 2,
        groupValue: selected,
        onChanged: (val) => modalSetState(() => selected = val),
        title: Text("Two")
      ),

    ])
  )
).whenComplete(() {
  print("Selected: $selected");
});
```

In my example `setState` for the content of the modal is declared as `modalSetState` builder argument.

Comment: Wow i missed this `StatefulBuilder` widget , Thanks @George !!

Answer (score 13):

@George already provided solution, but here is a complete example when working with SearchDelegate:

```
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
    bool _isItemSelected = true;

    //...rest of the @override methods

    @override
    Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
        return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return CheckboxListTile(
                    title: const Text('Item'),
                    value: _isItemSelected,
                    onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                        setState(() {
                            _isItemSelected = newValue;
                        });
                    },
            );
    });
  }
}
```