# How to setState inside showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any limitation in BottomSheet that we cannot update the widget states? As you can see in the example below I'm using a Switch but its display is not changing, although the value update, it's just that it doesn't get re-render again.

This is part of StatefulWidget right now.

This same problem I'm experiencing with the DropdownButton widget. These both work in normal page fine.

Does anybody have the idea?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheet(
      onClosing: () {},
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Switch(
          onChanged: (bool v) {
            debugPrint('v is ${v.toString()}');
            // b = v; <<-- This is also not working when using StatelessWidget
            setState(() => b = v);
            debugPrint(b.toString());
          },
          value: b,
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56321614/6374527

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The problem here is that the [`BottomSheet`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) you are creating is **not part of** your `StatefulWidget`. If you only made your widget stateful for the purpose of using `setState` inside of `showModalBottomSheet`, you can revert that change now.

What you really want to do is set the state inside of your `BottomSheet`. You do that by either passing a `StatefulWidget` to the `builder` or by using a [`StatefulBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html), which I will do for this example for the sake of simplicity:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return BottomSheet(
      onClosing: () {},
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        bool b = false;
        return StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, setState) => Switch(
            onChanged: (bool v) {
              setState(() => b = v);
            },
            value: b,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

I also moved the `b` value inside the `builder` function of the `BottomSheet`.

If you want to use the value of `b` inside of your original `StatefulWidget` as well, you would move it out again and you probably want to call `this.setState` as well to also update the other widget (only if you need it to update).

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking to pass the StatefulWidget, but this will also do. However I used BLOC to update the widget meanwhile.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what i need. Very simply.

Answer (score 27):

I also faced the same problem. Its a small trick, you need to insert `StatefulBuilder` in the showModalBottomSheet. I will use a different code to make someone out there understand easily using checkbox now that the answer comes way late.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
    mpesachecked =false;
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter mystate) {
          return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 70.0, 20.0, 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                 Checkbox(
                      value: mpesachecked,
                      activeColor: Colors.green,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        mystate(() {
                          mpesachecked = value;
                        });
                      }),
                 ])
                 ));
               });
    )
```

NOTE: the new **state** within the showModalBottomSheet is **mystate**

Comment: this is correct!!! worked